# Can we build a Staff Directory. show a picture of the person, their title, their phone number, their email and a Chat with me button (through teams)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-experience, microsoft-teams, people-directory

We have Office 365 + SharePoint online, and I am not sure if we can achieve this inside a SharePoint modern page:

Build a list which show a Staff Directory. This could show a picture of the person, their title, their phone number, their email and a Chat with me button (through teams).

Answer (score 1):

You can use OOTB People web part in SharePoint Online to show the users on modern experience page. But, you have to add user profiles manually in [people web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05).

---

For your requirement to show the teams chat, this is not possible using SharePoint OOTB capabilities, you have to create a custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) web part, which will fetch the user details & teams chat (if any API is available for that) and show them on page.

Check below SPFx samples created by community members. These will help you with developing UI and setting people card (`PersonaCard`) like SharePoint OOTB web part.

1. [People Directory](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-people-directory)
2. [Microsoft Graph People Search](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-msgraph-peoplesearch)

---

Accessing Microsoft Teams chat messages might be possible with Microsoft Graph APIs. Check below documentations if it helps:

1. [chatMessage resource type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0)
2. [List chats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
3. [Get chat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: thanks for the examples they can achieve 80% of what i am looking for.. the only thing is that i need to add a chat button beside each name, is this possible?

Comment: check updated answer for this. It might be possible using Microsoft graph APIs.

Comment: and how i can embed these calls inside the web parts?

Comment: You need developer experience for that. check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial) & [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-microsoft-graph-apis).

Comment: Hi @johnGu, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.